# Java URLClassLoader: select which classes to import

Tags: java, jar, urlclassloader

Currently I'm using this line to load a 3rd party JAR and add its packages/classes to my program

```
URL [] urls = new URL [] { "http://..." };
new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

The problem I have with this approach is that the whole JAR is loaded, meaning all packages and all classes are imported.
How can I tell URLClassLoaded to load only a few selected classes?

An example would be a JAR hierarchy like this

- package A

  - class 1
  - class 2
- package B

  - class 1
  - class 2
  - class 3
  - class 4

I'd like to do something like "import only A.* and B.class2"

Comment: Implement your own `ClassLoader`.

Comment: You will have to implement custom class loader as I have depicted in my answer and set that as the default class loader for loading the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a *custom implementation of ClassLoader*.

Override the `findClass()` method of the classloader and apply the business logic for selecting the classes that you want to be loaded.

```
class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

         public Class findClass(String name) {
             if(shouldBeLoaded)
                return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
         }
    }
```

Setting this as the default class loader for loading (optional)

```
java -Djava.system.class.loader
    =com.test.CustomClassLoader
```

Comment: Do I really need to set it as default? Shouldn't it be the same if I always call new CustomClassLoader() instead of new URLClassLoader()?

Comment: No you can do CustomClassLoader() too. You need not make that default.